# How to able javascript in Android WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've got this short code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mywebview.loadUrl("https://onet.pl");
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

How to able here javascript? I tried various version from stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me, i got a lot of errors. Anyone can help me?